# Connected Services and LoginServiceClient fails on Linux Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I have a C# program that runs perfectly under Windows 10.  It uses Connected Services that are added in Visual Studio 2017, so that I can add in additional Class and Method functions to connect to Ultimate Software's HR system and pull our employee information from.  What I would like to do is run this application under Linux CentOS.  I installed Mono for Linux on both CentOS 6 and CentOS 7; and verified 100% that it can and does run compiled Visual Studio C# programs under Linux.  No problem.

However, when I run the EXE program under Linux Mono, it does not connect to the external website defined in Connected Services.

Here is the line it is failing on.

```
    loginClient = new LoginServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_ILoginService");
```

And the error I get back, is (of course), a NullReferenceException as the defined object of 'loginClient' never gets instantiated.

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Has anyone ever successfully taken an EXE file for Windows using Connected Services and run it under Linux Mono?

If so, what do I need to do in my code to get that to work?

Thank you,

Comment: You need to look at the full Exception/Stacktrace

Comment: SushiHangover; I do have the full Exception stacktrace set; but it never gets to the exception on the 'try'.  I could add the full code snippet to the OP if that would help.